# Pixel on/off (or black/white) in a GUI

Tags: java, grid, coordinates, switch-statement, pixel

I was wondering If someone could help me understand how to turn pixels on/off or black/white.  To be more specific I am quite good with the TI-Basic programming language and an aspect of this language involves turning the calculators pixels on and off. I would like to make a form that is like 100x100 or so, and is broken up into a grid. So I could turn on / off the pixels in the form based on the grid. I have seen some code for this but I the code usually changes pixels according to the screen not the form. ( an example of this would be 1,1 changes the top pixel of the screen, so the form must be dragged there to correspond with the pixel). If anyone can point me in the right direction as to how I can achieve this. I would be very grateful!

-thank you very much, Matt

Answer (score 0):

In Swing or AWT (the frameworks that come with Java Standard Edition) you can to the following

```
   g.setColor( Color.BLACK ) ;
   g.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 ) ;
```

Where g is the Graphics object for the component you want to paint.  Typically g is the parameter of paint (for AWT) or paintComponent (for Swing). For a white pixel, use Color.WHITE.